# SceneBuilder LoadException

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have been working with SceneBuilder and all of a sudden i cant open my fxml file (created and edited ONLY with SceneBuilder), because of LoadExpcetion:Invalid property.

Could anyone take a look at the xml and tell me, what is wrong?

```
com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument$FxmlParseException: Failed to load FXML file
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument.makeParseException(FXMLDocument.java:400)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument.load(FXMLDocument.java:311)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument.checkLayout(FXMLDocument.java:239)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument.checkLayout(FXMLDocument.java:224)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.Project.forFxml(Project.java:835)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.Project.forFxml(Project.java:807)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.DesignerTool.loadFXMLLayout(DesignerTool.java:197)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.DesignerTool.loadFXMLLayout(DesignerTool.java:185)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.DesignerTool.commonInit(DesignerTool.java:513)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.DesignerTool.init(DesignerTool.java:457)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.SceneBuilderLauncher$RunningWithJMXInstance.launch(SceneBuilderLauncher.java:71)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.Main.start(Main.java:72)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:216)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Invalid property.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$PropertyElement.<init>(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2372)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2345)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2164)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument$2.call(FXMLDocument.java:301)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.util.Utils.withFXMLDefaultClassLoader(Utils.java:2216)
at com.oracle.javafx.authoring.persist.FXMLDocument.load(FXMLDocument.java:298)
... 21 more
```

The fxml file itself: http://pastebin.com/VtcJ5HKT

Comment: I'm able to open your fxml file without any problem. Using Scenebuilder 8.1.1, JDK 8u77

Answer (score 1):

Your FXML file can be opened using Gluon Scene Builder 8.1.1.
I also succeeded using an old Scene Builder 2.0.
Which SB are you using ?

Comment: Tried it with SB 1.1, got the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Removal of ...

```
 <opaqueInsets>
   <Insets />
 </opaqueInsets>
```

of the first `GridPane` (line 37-40) fixes the load problem for me.

Give it a try:)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, i was using old version of Scene Builder. I still have no idea why it stopped working by itself, but upgrading helped!